# Writing a method in Java about ArrayList (getting the first match among similar length)

Tags: arraylist

I am new to java and I am writing a method that returns the longest song from a playlist(ArrayList) using only the minutes. if multiple songs have the same longest length, it will return the first encountered song. How to ensure it returns the first longest song and not the last longest song.

```
public Song getLongestSong() {  
    if (this.songs.isEmpty()) {         
        return null;    
    }   
    Song longestSong = this.songs.get(0);   
    for (Song songs: this.songs) {      
        if (songs.getMinutes() >= longestSong.getMinutes()) {
            longestSong = songs;    `   
        }           
    }   
    return longestSong;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework assignment, so I'm not going to give an exact answer [https://cs.millersville.edu/~autolab/161-f21/mutunesobject/](https://cs.millersville.edu/%7Eautolab/161-f21/mutunesobject/).

Think about the check in the `if (songs.getMinutes() >= longestSong.getMinutes()` statement. If there is already a value set for `longestSong` and another song comes in with the same length, what will happen? How do you avoid that?